# Dynamic casting based on a string

Tags: c#, casting

Is there a way in C# to cast an object based on a string?

Example,

```
String typeToCast = control.GetType().Name;

Button b = (typeToCast)control;
```

Comment: to be honest, casting in that way would not make sense. There is no reason for you to do that.

Comment: I have a file with specified types to create. I could hard code the checks and create those objects like that, but I was looking for a more elegant way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't do that. Also, what would you achieve, as you have to assign it to "static" type, in your case, it's Button - So why not just cast it normally:

```
Button b = (Button)control;
```

You can hovewer, check if your control is of a type:

```
Type t = TypeFromString(name);
bool isInstanceOf = t.IsInstanceOfType(control);
```

Edit:
To create an object without having it type at compile time, you can use Activator class:

```
object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(TypeFromString(name));
Button button = (Button)obj; //Cast to compile-time known type.
```

Comment: Well then, you should ask if you can create an object, having it's type's name - yes you can.

Answer (score 7):

Yes you can but you should not.

Csharp

```
string value = "2.5";
object typedObject;
typedObject = Convert.ChangeType(value, Type.GetType("System.Double"));
```

Vbnet

```
Dim value As String = "2.5"
Dim typedObject As Object
typedObject = Convert.ChangeType(value, Type.GetType("System.Double"))
```